# Connect to Azure Storage Blob via FTP

Tags: ftp, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to connect to an Azure storage Blob via FTP for comparison purposes, I tried following the guide to connect to an Azure website via FTP but I can't seem to find ftp credentials as there is no publishing profile

Answer (score 0):

As in being able to upload/download blobs via an FTP client? If that is what you mean then, unfortunately, this isn't possible. This [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22047005/how-to-set-ftp-to-a-azure-cloud-service-or-azure-storage) might help if that is the scenario you're looking for.

Comment: No, I just wanted to be able to compare the contents of the blob with a local directory